# APScheduler missing jobs after adding misfire_grace_time

Tags: python, cron, apscheduler

I am running a BlockingScheduler process that it's suppose to run several `cron` jobs, but it fails to run every single time with the message:

`Run time of job "validation (trigger: cron[hour='3'], next run at: 2016-12-30 03:00:00 CST)" was missed by 0:00:02.549821`

I have the following setup:

```
sched = BlockingScheduler(misfire_grace_time=3600, coalesce=True)
sched.add_jobstore('mongodb', collection='my_jobs')

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', hour=3, id='validation')
def validation():
    rep = Myclass()
    rep.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sched.start()
```

I thought adding `misfire_grace_time` would do the trick, but every job is still missing to run.

Answer (score 11):

```
self.scheduler = BlockingScheduler(
    logger=log,
    job_defaults={'misfire_grace_time': 15*60},
)
```

adding the `misfire_grace_time` as `job_defaults` will work

Answer (score 7):

try adding misfire_grace_time in `@sched.scheduled_job('cron', hour=3, id='validation', misfire_grace_time=3600)`