# APScheduler misfire testing

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am attempting to test misfired tasks with APScheduler, but I am not seeing the missed tasks run when I restart APScheduler. I have configured APScheduler as follows:

**scheduler.py**

```py
def configure_scheduler():
    jobstores = {
        'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url=config('DATABASE_URL'))
    }
    sched = BlockingScheduler()
    sched.configure(jobstores=jobstores)
    sched.add_job(
        test_task,
        id='test_task', 
        'interval',  
        hours=1, 
        coalesce=True, 
        max_instances=1,
        misfire_grace_time=360, 
        replace_existing=True
    )
    return sched

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = configure_scheduler()
    scheduler.start()
```

When I start the scheduler the first time, `test_task` is added to the `apscheduler_jobs` table in my Postgres database with a `next_run_time` of one hour from when I start the scheduler. I then attempt to test a misfire by:

1. Changing `next_run_time` in my database to the current time
2. Waiting 15 seconds
3. Starting the scheduler

When I follow this procedure, the `next_run_time` is again set to an hour from the current time. The `next_run_time` appears to be updated in the [`update_job`](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/7e78cad90ce080825c46de8967d9573e9fc86353/apscheduler/jobstores/sqlalchemy.py#L97-L104) method of the SQLAlchemy jobstore. I have seen one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064033/apscheduler-cron-job-is-not-executing) related to persistent job store tasks not running after a misfire. The solution to most [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428118/apscheduler-missing-jobs-after-adding-misfire-grace-time) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896705/python-apscheduler-not-consistent) I have seen is to add the `misfire_grace_time` argument to `add_job`. I have tried this per my configuration above but have not had any luck running missed jobs on scheduler startup. Am I missing something related to how the `replace_existing` and `misfire_grace_time` arguments interact? Do I need to manually check if the `next_run_time` of any jobs is in the past, then run these jobs before starting the scheduler?

I am using v3.6.1 of the APScheduler library.

For additional context, I will be deploying the scheduler on Heroku and I am attempting to work around Heroku's [automatic dyno cycling](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) which occurs at least once per day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [some discussion](https://gitter.im/apscheduler/Lobby?at=5db7339b9c398215099ec78a) on the APScheduler Gitter chat room with Alex Grönholm (the creator of APScheduler), I was able to determine that the job was being "overwritten" in my database because I have `replace_existing=True` in my call to `add_job`. This causes the scheduler to replace the job in the jobstore every time the scheduler starts.

**My workaround**

1. Before the scheduler starts, check the `apscheduler_jobs` table for existing jobs.
2. For each job in the database, check the `next_run_time` against the current time. If the `next_run_time` is in the past, run the job now.
3. Schedule the jobs as before, using `replace_existing=True`.
4. Start the scheduler.

Comment: I tried this suggestion by Alex Grönholm (the creator of APScheduler). Start a BackgroundScheduler, add the jobs and make the main program run a `while True` loop. I was able to run the missed jobs.